# Measurability of a version of a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

If $X$ is a ($\mathcal{F}$-measurable) random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ and $Y$ is a version of $X$ in the sense that $\mathbf{P}(X \ne Y) = 0$ and $\{X \ne Y \} \in \mathcal{F}$, does it follow that $Y$ is also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable ?

I am trying to prove that $\mathbf{L^2}(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbf{P})$ is a closed subset of $\mathbf{L^2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$ for $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ but the question of versions bothers me. If $X_n \to X$ in $\mathbf{L^2}$, then $X$ can be chosen to be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, but $X$ might as well not be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable (unless the answer to my previous question is true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is complete then $Y$ is measurable. Just having $\{ X \neq Y \} \in \mathcal{F}$ is not enough, because you need subsets of it to also be measurable in order to have preimages of intervals with $Y$ be measurable.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you are referring to this situation: $(Y \in B) = (Y \in B, Y=X) \cup (Y \in B, Y \ne X)$, the second set being a subset of a set of measure $0$. Please see the edit to my question. Is it sufficient that $\mathcal{G}$ be complete to avoid the inconsistencies?

Comment: @Nocturne I think you need $\mathcal{G}$ to be complete for the question to even make sense, because strictly speaking $L^2_\mathcal{G}$ will not even be a subset of $L^2_\mathcal{F}$ otherwise. But once you assume that I think your problems go away.